# Java LDAP auth with a non-cleartext password

Tags: java, security, authentication, ldap, jndi

JNDI LDAP auth requires a cleartext password to be passed (Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS) to almost all security mechanisms (or at least how I understand it). It looks like to be designed in a way, that the password originates from the current JVM. But what about a password, that has to be sent from another machine? This approach forces it to be sent in a recoverable fashion (the most simple is cleartext) with little security.

To be more specific, let's consider a 3-tier setup: client, java server and an LDAP server. The user enters the username and password in the client which is sent to the java server. Then the java server communicates with an LDAP server in order to authorize these credentials. Is there a way to make the transmission from the client to the java server secure?
I understand, that we can use SSL or another way to secure the channel itself, but it's still no good that we have to send the password in a recoverable fashion through this (even secure) channel.

I tried to search for an answer, but it looks like most of them consider a 2-tier setup. There were also some 3d party java libraries recommendations (instead of JNDI), but it wasn't clear, if that they can handle my task. If they actually do so, could you please give an example utilizing them for my task?

My target platforms are Delphi XE3 Client, Java SE 6 Server and an AD LDAP. But I'm also interested in a more theoretical discussion not restricted to these concrete client and LDAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the answer and actually made it work on a production system.
The correct path is to use the Kerberos protocol http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol).

In my setup the following happens:

1) The client obtains a ticket to the server service in the AD and sends it to the server. This is done via classes near `TSSPIWinNTCredentials` class in `Indy`, but I think it's quite possible to do so without difficulties using Windows functions directly.

2) The server logins to the AD as a service. This is done via `LoginContext` class using correct `AppConfigurationEntry` with keys.

3) The server authenticates the client in the AD using client's ticket, obtaining client's username. This is done via `Subject.doAs` method and classes near `GSSManager` class.

4) The server performs additional business level checks and grants the client a business session. This is business-specific of course.

At no point in this scenario any insecure communication is made, including sending passwords in a recoverable fashion, because it is the design goal of the Kerberos protocol itself.

Answer (score 1):

> This approach forces it to be sent in a recoverable fashion (the most simple is cleartext) with little security.

The approach requires you to use SSL. It's as simple as that.

Comment: I mentioned about using SSL, but isn't it still not quite correct to send a recoverable password even over SSL? We can imagine a fraud system administrator on the server end, who can eavesdrop this password. Overall, as i understand the whole idea is to hash the password as soon as possible (just after the user enters it) and "forget" it, using only unrecoverable variant afterwards (for transmitting and storing)?

Comment: No. LDAP clients should probably not send pre-encoded passwords to servers. Using pre-encoded passwords prevents the server from performing password history and quality checks. Authentication and authorization should always use SSL with a high-quality cipher, or a non-secure connection that has been promoted to a secure connection using the StartTLS Extended Request.

Comment: Does this mean that SASL authentication mechanisms in JNDI actually send the password in a recoverable variant? For example, CRAM-MD5 or Digest-MD5 send to LDAP not hashes, but real passwords?

Comment: An SSL server is required to provide a certificate to authenticate itself. The client should verify the server's identity before sending it any confidential information.

Comment: But SSL only protects the channel, not the endpoint. As i mentioned in the first comment, this solution does not defend against a fraud system administrator operating on a server end. He can eavesdrop the real password and then cleanly login into the system using not some hacks, but real client software! What I'm trying to say, is that unrecoverable passwords (and also with some nonce values or smth else against replay attacks) are a must have today. And SSL does not solve these problems. Or am I mistaken?